# Trying to install proprietary NVidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, dkms

I'm trying to install the Nvidia driver from the Nvidia website on Ubuntu 19.04.

I'm executing `sudo tellinit 3` in the console and then run the Nvidia installer script. But I'm getting stuck on:

> Installing DKMS kernel module

It remains on 5% progress and nothing happens. What should I do?

Comment: This situation is why there is the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot` command in Ubuntu to automatically select and install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

> Installing DKMS kernel module

This message is trying to tell you that the kernel is running DKMS. And DKMS (dynamic kernel module service) is trying to build (i.e. compile) the relevant graphics driver for your system and for this specific kernel. Each kernel needs to build from scratch x4 specific Nvidia .KO files that are needed to run the graphics card & drivers. If the x4 .KO files are missing you wont have a fully functioning graphics card or no video acceleration or wrong video resolution. Hope this makes sense. YES! its complication for sure.

Comment: And what should be done to get rid of this problem?